# SendKeys.SendWait permission denied error when RDP is closed

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I'm trying to launch a program and I have to enter login and password into it.

To simulate keystrokes I'm using the next code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(login + "\t" + password + "\n\r");
```

Unfortuantely, I am to do all these actions on a server with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 OS and I have to use RDP. When RDP connection is active, everything is OK, but if the RDP window is closed or minimized, SendWait invokes an exception with message 'permission denied'.

How can I emulate keystrokes when RDP is disconnected?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds fair, there is no desktop anymore to send the keys to.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102789/automated-send-keys-failing-when-no-rdp) by [David Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600214/david-johnson)

Create a batch file with the following commands and save it to the desktop of the workstation you want to keep unlocked: I have named my file Logoff.bat

```
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 0 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 1 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 2 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 2 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 3 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 4 /dest:console
START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 5 /dest:console
```

Tscon.exe comes standard with your windows installation and is specifically created to leave a Previously-Locked Console Unlocked. See this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302801

The next time you log in to the workstation with remote desktop, do not log out the normal way, but run you batch file - in my case "Logoff.bat" This will terminate your Remote Desktop connection and log you out, but will then continue in an unlocked state for any scripts to run as if someone is actually logged in.